# What is the difference between query.get and query.filter_by(id=id) and when would I use filter_by?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get) it is stated that

> get() is special in that it provides direct access to the identity map of the owning Session.

This is in many ways similar to `query.filter_by(id == id)` or `query.filter(ModelClass.id == id)` (in which I assume that ModelClass.id is it's primary key).

It seems to me that I would *always* want to use `query.get` because it is faster (due to not having to perform a `SELECT`). Why would I ever want use `filter_by(id=id)`?

Answer (score 0):

`.get` does perform `SELECT` when needed, there's no way around. But yes, `.get` is smart enough to bypass DB query when possible.

If you're filtering by `id` only, there's no reasons to use `filter` — it's just more general thing.